# Why the ngFor is looping through a JSON array but returns empty property values?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

Been looping through a json array using ngFor but it returns empty.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let h of HeroesWebAPI" (click)= "OnSelectedFunc(h)"> {{h.Name}} </li>
</ul>
```

returned arary is:

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"John-1"},{"Id":2,"Name":"John-2"}]
```

Service

```
  getHeroesFromWebAPI(): Observable<any>
  {    
    return this.http.get<any>("https://localhost:44320/api/values").pipe(
      map(res => JSON.stringify(res))
    );
  }
```

Component.ts

```
HeroesWebAPI:  any[]= [];

getHeroes(): void
     {
        console.log("getHeroes called");
        this.heroService.getHeroesFromWebAPI().subscribe( r => {this.HeroesWebAPI= [r]; 
          console.log("Final hit:"+  [this.HeroesWebAPI])});  
     }
```

Comment: Aren't you returning a string instead of an object from the getHeroesFromWebAPI due to the `JSON.stringify(res)` ?

Comment: @AlbertoRivera: yeah, a JSON string, should be iterated, right?

Comment: If you do it that way, you will iterate over each character in the string. If you want to access the properties, you should use the array itself

Comment: Use the array? how? can you show me in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service should return the array from the response. Assuming your response looks like the returned array you showed:

```
getHeroesFromWebAPI(): Observable<any>
  {    
    return this.http.get<any>("https://localhost:44320/api/values");
  }
```

Then later in your getHeroes

```
this.heroService.getHeroesFromWebAPI().subscribe( r => {this.HeroesWebAPI=r; 
          console.log("Final hit:"+  [this.HeroesWebAPI])});
```

Comment: ahhh. It worked. Thanks but still it's mind boggling that how did it work?

see, the console.log shows object object, which is exactly what have been returned, so how did it manage to loop through some Object Object

Comment: also, does the observable return JSON by default?

Comment: The observable returns JSON object by default. The reason the console log shows that output is because you are concatenating a string to an array. You should use `console.log("Final hit:", this.HeroesWebAPI)` (note the comma instead of the +) if you want to inspect the array @afaaqadabookick

Comment: let me check Alberto

Comment: just 1 last quick question. Is JSON string (that I was doing using stringify) and JSON object array that I have returned now, are different?

Isn't every JSON object a string already?

Comment: Nope. A JSON string is the string representation of the actual JSON object. You can look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String to get familiar with strings and objects in Javascript

Answer (score 0):

```html
<ul  *ngFor="let h of HeroesWebAPI" >
    <li(click)= "OnSelectedFunc(h.id,h.Name)"> {{h.Name}} </li>
</ul>
```

```js
OnSelectedFunc(id, name) {
  console.log(`ID:${id},Name:${name}`)
}
```

Comment: {{h.Name}}

I am doing the same bro, but not working.

Comment: that means the JSON data is not mapped to this.HeroesWebAPI so apply the Alberto Rivera posted

Comment: hi check my comments on his post,